# OLD question suddenly goes to top of inbox

Tags: discussion, support

[Thunderbird won't ask for NNTP password—how to fix?](https://superuser.com/questions/1006369/thunderbird-wont-ask-for-nntp-password-how-to-fix)

A few minutes ago, this question was shown at the top of my in-box and highlighted as new.  I looked and saw that the last change was eight months ago.  Then it was removed from the in-box.

Bug?  Gremlin?  Some sort of system reminder to look at it?

Comment: My guess.  Somebody submitted a comment and it was deleted before you viewed it

Comment: Maybe it was upvoted?

Comment: No, votes go on the rep list.  Responses go in the inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that there was either a spam post or "me too" answer submitted and it was removed by the time you viewed the question. It is not at all uncommon for questions to be wrongly resurrected that way but the review queue normally sorts them out quite quickly.

Comment: Accepted as the _probable_ answer.

Comment: I just checked and there are no deleted answers on the question.

Comment: @Ben N: Perhaps spam answers get deleted completely when the relevant user is permanently banned?

Comment: Checking in the data explorer it seems that even spam answers don't get completely removed from the database. Perhaps Ramhound was right and it was a comment instead.

Comment: 10K+ users can always see all deleted content (unless it was manually removed for legal reasons, which is a super rare occurrence). The inbox item was probably from a comment :)